# Proving a challenging inequality on finite summations

Tags: inequality

Let $\mathbf{p} := (p_1,\dots,p_n)$ and $\mathbf{q} := (q_1,\dots,q_n)$ be two finite sequences of real numbers such that:

$$0 \le p_i \le 1, \sum_{i=1}^{n}p_i = 1,$$
$$0 \le q_i \le 1, \sum_{i=1}^{n}q_i = 1.$$

Assume that $q_1 > p_1$ and for all $k$ $(1 < k < n)$, we have $q_k - p_k \ge q_{k+1} - p_{k+1}$.

Using these facts and assuming without loss of generality that $|q_1 - p_1| > |p_n - q_n|$, how would you establish that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}q_jp_i - \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}p_jq_i > (q_1-p_1)^2?$$

For the case that $n=2$, subtracting the right-hand-side from the left-hand-side gives:

$$
\begin{align}
q_1p_2 - p_1q_2 -(q_1-p_1)^2
    &=  q_1(1-p_1)-p_1(1-q_1)-(q_1-p_1)^2\\
    &=  q_1-q_1p_1-p_1+p_1q_1-(q_1-p_1)^2\\
    &=  (q_1-p_1)-(q_1-p_1)^2\\
    &> 0
\end{align}
$$
where the final inequality follows from $0 \le p_1 < q_1 \le 1$.

Comment: This inequality is a conjecture.

Comment: Can you prove it for n=2? n=3?

Comment: For $n=2$ yes (the only solution to the resulting system would be $\mathbf{p} = \mathbf{q}$; the inequality holds for all other sequences).

Comment: @martycohen I have appended the proof for $n=2$. Perhaps this suggests a proof by induction? Not sure how that would be established here.